# Are these definition equivalent about a periodic point?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Given a dynamical system $(X,G)$,

def1. A point $x\in X$ is called periodic, if there exist a syndetic set $S\subseteq G$, such that $Sx=\{x\}$.

def2. A point $x\in X$ is called periodic, if $Gx$ is a minimal and finite subset of $X$.

def3. A point $x\in X$ is called periodic, if $G/G_x$ is compact, where $G$ is a topological group and $G_x$ is the isotropy group of $x$.

Are these definition equivalent?